# How to source /etc/profile for Remote Desktop Sessions

Tags: bash, login, remote-desktop, profile, xrdp

I want to set up a server with some functions and aliases available for all users.

I set these up initially in a file in `/etc/profile.d` and everything was working fine both from:

- SSH
- Local desktop (Gnome 3)

I then set up Remote Desktop access with `xrdp`. But the Bash terminals started from within the Remote Desktop environment apparently don't source `/etc/profile`.

How could this be achieved in a reasonable manner?

##### Attempt 1

I tried to mimic `/etc/gdm3/Xsession` and added the line

```
. /etc/profile
```

to `/etc/X11/Xsession`, but that was no good as the Remote Desktop would no longer start.

Comment: Are you able to configure the terminal in any way? You'd like the terminal to start your shell as a "login shell".

Comment: Yes. I know that I want to have the "login shell" behaviour. The question is how to configure that?